# how to delete the particular selected item from the list of items in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I followed http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=8 this one to add the values in the spinner.In it while we select the "clear spinner items" the whole events are will be delete. But i need to  the selected particular item only want to delete.Any one can help me.. The sample code will help to me lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete particular item from spinner you have to remove it from arrayadapter which you are using for filling it.

So first get the position of item you are wanting to delete.

Then get the object from arrayadapter from its position by method.

```
int pos = 0;
object t= m_adapterForSpinner.getitem(pos); // where m_arrayadapter is array adapter using for filling spinner
```

And then remove it from spinner by using following code:

```
m_adapterForSpinner.remove((CharSequence) t);
```

Then fill your spinner again with arrayadapter.

Comment: sorry to asking this: object cannot be resolved to a type and pos cannot be resolved error is coming

Comment: @ezhil write Object t(O in uppercase) and you have to define pos urself by getting position of item you wan to del.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the selected item in the spinner:

```
adapter.remove((String)spinner.getSelectedItem());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where "adapter" is the adapter set to the spinner, it's as simple as that. :)

if adapter is out of scope you can get the adapter from the spinner, cast properly and remove the item:

```
((List<String>) spinner.getAdapter()).remove((String)spinner.getSelectedItem());
((List<String>) spinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```