# How to remove a particular Item from a spinner

Tags: android

In my application i have spinners,if there are 10 items in a spinner  how can i delete some specific item (like 3rd or 4th) from that spinner i used below code but not succeeded.

```
 for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
     Object t= cropT.getItem(i);
     ((ArrayAdapter<String>) cropT).remove((String) t);
     spinnerCropType.setAdapter(cropT);
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778745/how-to-delete-the-particular-selected-item-from-the-list-of-items-in-spinner

Comment: Same thing mentioned in the above link i am using but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set adapter everytime your delete items from it. In fact, after removing items from your spinner, you need to call **notifyDataSetChanged()** method on your adapter to refresh the spinner

```
//for example
adapterSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: show us the entire code, like how you are initializing and setting adapter